# Visual Studio gives error about ambiguous ctor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm stuck with compiler errors in VS 2013 where my custom class has an ambiguity error, but it works without ambiguity for `std::vector`

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyArray
{
public:
    std::vector< int > values;
    MyArray(int s) : values(s) { }
    MyArray(std::initializer_list< int >list) { values = list; }
};

int main ()
{
    vector<int> vx({9,8,7}); // Works
    MyArray mx({9, 8, 7});   // Works

    vector<int> vy({9});     // Works
    MyArray my({9});         // VS-compiler complains about ambiguity
    MyArray mz(std::initializer_list<int>{9}); // Works
}
```

Of course, I can fix the ambiguity by added the type explicitly: `MyArray my(std::initializer_list<int>{9})`, but that is very inconvenient. **Is there a way to code up the constructors so that VS doesn't complain about ambiguity for my class?**

Since `std::vector` doesn't give ambiguity errors, it would seem like it should be possible.

Comment: This is definitely a bug. MSVC is happy if you don't use parentheses - `MyArray my{9};`

Comment: No, that would call the integer ctor (which sets the size) instead of setting the content through the initializer list as is intended.

Comment: No it doesn't. It calls the `initializer_list` constructor (as it should) and initializes the `values` vector to a single element containing `9`

Comment: I stand corrected. This might actually solve my practical problems for the entire code base.

Comment: As it is perfectly legal to write ``int x = { 5 };`` in C++11, it seems the VS compiler is as confused about c++11 as I am ;) The ``{9}`` could as much be an initializer_list as a ["uniform initializer"](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) for an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using std::size_t in your other constructor

You'll be in the same boat if you do size_t as your vector template parameter... but it's a workaround for the other cases until this is fixed.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyArray
{
public:
    std::vector< int > values;
    MyArray(std::size_t s) : values(s) { }
    MyArray(std::initializer_list<int> list): values(list)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    int s({ 9 });
    vector<int> vx({ 9, 8, 7 }); // Works
    MyArray mx({ 9, 8, 7 });   // Works

    vector<int> vy({ 9 });     // Works
    MyArray my1(0);
    MyArray my({ 9 });         // VS-compiler complains about ambiguity
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it seems it is a bug of MS VC++ 2013 compiler.

According to the C++ Standard (13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization, p.#1)

> — Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
>   constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
>   the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload
>   resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>   the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
>   elements of the initializer list.

As such a constructor is found in your class it shall be called.

At least this code is compiled with GCC.

You may write a defect report to Microsoft. Usually they suggest a way to overcome the problem.
Do not forget to test the code setting off the MS language extensions for the project.